# blazor wont build from solution template Rider

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, jetbrains-rider

hello everyone :slight_smile: noob here,

on arch linux,

i've been building blazor webassembly apps for a week it's been fine all of a sudden they just dont work anymore, i keep getting this error from Jetbrains Rider

```
_Imports.razor(10, 23): [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'PickACardBlazor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

and this is from a fresh solution template as creatd by Jetbrains Rider .net Core blazor web assembly app.
the projects i have here that used to work all have the same error message.

running `dotnet run` in the project dir works fine it's just Rider's configuration runner's where the problem is

any insight would be much appreciated

here are some logs if they would help

```
Build started 07/12/2023 01:04:56.
Logging verbosity is set to: Normal.     1>Project "/home/pum/RiderProjects/test/test/test.csproj" on node 1 (build target(s)).
     1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
       Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo:
       Skipping target "CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       _DiscoverMvcApplicationParts:
         Creating "obj/Debug/net7.0/test.MvcApplicationPartsAssemblyInfo.cache" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
       CoreCompile:
         /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet exec "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.107/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll" /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,IL2121,1701,1702 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt /warn:7 /define:TRACE;DEBUG;NET;NET7_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NET6_0_OR_GREATER;NET7_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER /highentropyva+ /nullable:enable /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization/7.0.7/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components/7.0.7/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms/7.0.7/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web/7.0.7/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly/7.0.7/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.metadata/7.0.7/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/7.0.4/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.configuration/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.abstractions/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.physical/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.filesystemglobbing/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions/7.0.1/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.options/7.0.1/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.primitives/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.jsinterop/7.0.7/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.JSInterop.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.jsinterop.webassembly/7.0.7/lib/net7.0/Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/mscorlib.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/netstandard.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.AppContext.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Buffers.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.Immutable.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.Specialized.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Configuration.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Console.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Core.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Data.Common.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Data.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Drawing.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Formats.Asn1.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Formats.Tar.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Globalization.Calendars.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Globalization.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Globalization.Extensions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Compression.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll /reference:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/system.io.pipelines/7.0.0/lib/net7.0/System.IO.Pipelines.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Pipes.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Linq.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Linq.Expressions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Linq.Parallel.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Linq.Queryable.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Memory.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Http.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Http.Json.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.HttpListener.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Mail.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.NameResolution.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Ping.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Primitives.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Quic.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Requests.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Security.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.ServicePoint.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Sockets.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebClient.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebProxy.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebSockets.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Numerics.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ObjectModel.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Emit.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Resources.Reader.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Resources.Writer.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Handles.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Loader.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.AccessControl.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Claims.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Principal.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Security.SecureString.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ServiceProcess.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Encoding.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Json.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Channels.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Overlapped.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Tasks.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Thread.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Timer.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Transactions.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Transactions.Local.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.ValueTuple.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Web.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Web.HttpUtility.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Windows.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.Serialization.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XDocument.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XPath.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll /reference:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/ref/net7.0/WindowsBase.dll /debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj/Debug/net7.0/test.dll /refout:obj/Debug/net7.0/refint/test.dll /target:exe /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:11.0 /analyzerconfig:obj/Debug/net7.0/test.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig /analyzerconfig:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.107/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/analyzers/build/config/analysislevel_7_default.editorconfig /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.107/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/../analyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.107/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/../analyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll /analyzer:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.analyzers/7.0.7/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Analyzers.dll /analyzer:/home/pum/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions/7.0.1/analyzers/dotnet/roslyn4.4/cs/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Generators.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.Interop.JavaScript.JSImportGenerator.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.Interop.LibraryImportGenerator.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.Interop.SourceGeneration.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.7/analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generator.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.107/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/targets/../source-generators/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.107/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/targets/../source-generators/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.107/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/targets/../source-generators/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.dll /analyzer:/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.107/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/targets/../source-generators/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll /additionalfile:App.razor /additionalfile:Pages/Counter.razor /additionalfile:Pages/FetchData.razor /additionalfile:Pages/Index.razor /additionalfile:Shared/SurveyPrompt.razor /additionalfile:_Imports.razor /additionalfile:Shared/MainLayout.razor /additionalfile:Shared/NavMenu.razor Program.cs obj/Debug/net7.0/test.GlobalUsings.g.cs "obj/Debug/net7.0/.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj/Debug/net7.0/test.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605,SYSLIB0011
     1>/media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
     1>/media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
     1>/media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
     1>/media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
     1>/media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
     1>/media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
     1>/media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
     1>/media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
         CompilerServer: server - server processed compilation - 48cb383d-ad2a-4300-a7f9-93bd53bb3ce0
     1>Done Building Project "/home/pum/RiderProjects/test/test/test.csproj" (build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

       "/home/pum/RiderProjects/test/test/test.csproj" (build target) (1) ->
       (CoreCompile target) -> 
         /media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
         /media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
         /media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
         /media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
         /media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
         /media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
         /media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
         /media/hdd/home_dirs/RiderProjects/test/test/_Imports.razor(10,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

    0 Warning(s)
    8 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.96
```

when i comment out that line in the `_Imports.razor`:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Http
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using test
@using test.Shared <--**this one**
```

then it does work, but i didn't have to do that before. and it does work fine when i just run `dotnet run` from the commandline as is

Comment: does it work when using `dotnet build`? If yes, try to clear the Rider caches

Comment: @mu88 ty for replying. 
dotnet build does work. it is still builld successful tried it just now
i have just done what you suggested by following the steps here:
 [invalidated caches option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Invalidate_caches.html) same issue though :( I also have reinstalled the app and deleted all the relevant dirs in .local .cache and .config both from the AUR package manager and the jetbrains toolbox app, no luck

Comment: can you share your code, e. g. via GitHub?

Comment: it's a fresh blazor web assemply app template i generated with rider. as soon as the solution completes generating i select the run configuration option and this will happen.

Answer (score 1):

apparently this is a [known issue](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/12445579718802-blazor-wont-build-from-solution-template?page=1#community_comment_12446617143058) according to a representative from JetBrains